# Counterexample Request - 3 Easy Limit Questions

Tags: calculus

Let $f,g$ be two functions defined on $[a, \infty] $  for some $a$ .

Give a counterexample to the following statements:

1) If $ \lim_{x\to \infty } (f(x)-g(x)) = \infty $ , then  $ \lim_{x\to \infty } (\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} )= \infty $

2) If $ \lim_{x\to \infty } (\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} )= \infty $,  then  $ \lim_{x\to \infty } (f(x)-g(x)) = \infty $

3) If $ \lim_{x\to \infty } |\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} |= \infty $,  then  $ \lim_{x\to \infty } |f(x)-g(x)| = \infty $

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f(x)=1$,

$1)$ $g(x)=-x$.  $2,3) \ g(x)=\frac{1}{x}.$

Answer (score 0):

Hints:  For 1) you need $f$ to grow faster than $g$, but not too much faster.  For 2) you can let $g$ get small.  For 3, if your answer to 2 had both $f$ and $g$ positive, the same one will work.

Answer (score 0):

1. $f(x)=x^2+x+1; \;\; g(x)=x^2.$
2. $f(x)=\dfrac{1}{x};\;\; g(x)=\dfrac{1}{x^2}.$
3. $f(x)=\dfrac{1}{x};\;\; g(x)=\dfrac{1}{x^2}.$